# Cannot install Virtual Box onto Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

I downloaded the deb file from the main website, and ran it through software center, but when I try to install it, I get this error message:

```
dpkg: considering removing virtualbox in favour of virtualbox-4.2 ...
dpkg: no, cannot proceed with removal of virtualbox (--auto-deconfigure will help):
virtualbox-qt depends on virtualbox (= 4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.3)
virtualbox is to be removed.
dpkg: regarding .../virtualbox-4.2_4.2.16-86992~Ubuntu~quantal_i386.deb containing      virtualbox-4.2:
virtualbox-4.2 conflicts with virtualbox
virtualbox (version 4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.3) is present and installed.
dpkg: error processing /home/prob74/Downloads/virtualbox-4.2_4.2.16- 86992~Ubuntu~quantal_i386.deb (--install):
conflicting packages - not installing virtualbox-4.2
```

Comment: Did you remove the previous version you have installed?

Comment: Annd, that fixed it. I feel stupid now.

Moral of the story, don't rely on the software center...

Comment: Post an answer.  Post how you removed it and how you installed it.

Comment: You got your moral reversed, the reason you had this problem is because you did _not_ rely on the software center, not the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

virtualbox-4.2 was trying to replace virtualbox-4.1.12 but virtualbox-qt still had its dependency on virtualbox-4.1.12.

Remove both virtualbox and virtualbox-qt using

`sudo dpkg -r virtualbox-qt`

sudo dpkg -r virtualbox

and try to reinstall virtualbox-4.2 again.

P.S. Do use apt-get if you're able to.

Answer (score 1):

As it is clear from the error message the ubuntu software center is unable to remove
`old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules`, `VirtualBox pci kernel module`.

You may have older version of virtual box installed onto your system

This can be fixed by installing the package from terminal rather than depending on software center.
Use `sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-4.3_4.3.6-91406~Ubuntu~precise_i386.deb`

once done

run it using `virtualbox &` command